# Wait until page is fully loaded in BackstopJS

Tags: puppeteer, backstop.js

I've a scenario where I need to search. The problem is that I need BackstopJS to wait until an animated gif is done, and after that take screenpicture. I've tried this:

```
  {
  "label": "My_search",
  "cookiePath": "backstop_data/engine_scripts/cookies.json",
  "url": "https://my.test.com/test/#/search",
  "referenceUrl": "https://my.stage.test.com/test/#/search",
  "clickSelector": "#page-wrap > search > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span",
  "delay": 15000
}
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the load eventListener to your page and then log a readyEvent String for BackstopJS

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  console.log('pageLoaded');
});
```

in your backstop scenario use `"readyEvent": "pageLoaded",`